# $type in AlertRule Condition in ARM Template

Tags: azure, templates, azure-application-insights, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

I'm new to ARM templates and I'm working on a template to deploy a web test and an alert rule to an application insights instance. The app insights is created and maintained using Terraform but alert rules and web tests are not properly supported in Terraform yet. I was using an example taken from [this Github issue](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/1687) but we now want to separate it into an ARM step in the Azure DevOps pipeline as we need to obtain the URL for the webhook alert which we can't do easily inside the Terraform script.

I've been cleaning up what came from this example and using [this quickstart template](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/201-dynamic-web-tests) as a reference point. However I've noticed something in the quickstart example which I don't have in my example and I cannot seem to find any information on it.

In the alert rule definition properties object we have the condition object which has an `odata.type` and the associated `dataSource` has an `odata.type` as well like so:

```json
"properties": {
    "name": "[parameters('test').name]",
    "description": "[parameters('test').description]",
    "isEnabled": true,
    "condition": {
        "odata.type": "Microsoft.Azure.Management.Insights.Models.LocationThresholdRuleCondition",
        "dataSource": {
            "odata.type": "Microsoft.Azure.Management.Insights.Models.RuleMetricDataSource",
            "resourceUri": "[resourceId('microsoft.insights/webtests/', parameters('test').name)]",
            "metricName": "GSMT_AvRaW"
         },
         "windowSize": "PT5M",
         "failedLocationCount": "[parameters('test').failedLocationCount]"
},
```

The quickstart example is almost identical, but before the `odata.type` entries is a `$type` entry like so:

```json
"properties": {
    "name": "[parameters('tests')[copyIndex(1)].name]",
    "description": "[parameters('tests')[copyIndex(1)].description]",
    "isEnabled": true,
    "condition": {
      "$type": "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Monitoring.Alerts.Models.LocationThresholdRuleCondition, Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Mon.Client",
      "odata.type": "Microsoft.Azure.Management.Insights.Models.LocationThresholdRuleCondition",
      "dataSource": {
        "$type": "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Monitoring.Alerts.Models.RuleMetricDataSource, Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Mon.Client",
        "odata.type": "Microsoft.Azure.Management.Insights.Models.RuleMetricDataSource",
        "resourceUri": "[resourceId('microsoft.insights/webtests/', parameters('tests')[copyIndex()].name)]",
        "metricName": "GSMT_AvRaW"
      },
      "windowSize": "PT15M",
      "failedLocationCount": "[parameters('tests')[copyIndex(1)].failedLocationCount]"
    },
```

My template seems to work nonetheless, but should I include the `$type` properties? Or are they dependent upon use case? I've not had a lot of success in finding any documentation on this.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a possible error , if it doesn’t mention $type in the Action and condition something like below:

```
"condition": {
      "$type": "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Monitoring.Alerts.Models.ThresholdRuleCondition, Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Mon.Client",
      "odata.type": "Microsoft.Azure.Management.Insights.Models.ThresholdRuleCondition",
      "dataSource": {
        "$type": "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Monitoring.Alerts.Models.RuleMetricDataSource, Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Mon.Client",
        "odata.type": "Microsoft.Azure.Management.Insights.Models.RuleMetricDataSource",
        "resourceUri": "[resourceId('microsoft.insights/components', variables('appInsName'))]",
        "metricName": "request.duration"
      },
      "threshold": "[parameters('responseTime')]",
      "windowSize": "PT5M"
    },
    "actions": [
      {
        "$type": "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Monitoring.Alerts.Models.RuleEmailAction, Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Mon.Client",
        "odata.type": "Microsoft.Azure.Management.Insights.Models.RuleEmailAction",
        "sendToServiceOwners": true,
        "customEmails": []
      }
```

Error while running this script:

```
New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -Verbose -ResourceGroupName rg.test.ARM -TemplateFile azuredeploy.json -TemplateParameterFile azuredeploy.parameters.json -DeploymentDebugLogLevel All
```

Error message: Error- There is no target resource for this alert CPU default-app-name-plan.

So ideally one should give the $type in the condition and action to avoid this error while deploying from PowerShell/cli.

There is also an similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50056600/azure-arm-there-is-no-target-resource-for-this-alert).

Comment: I'm executing this using an Azure DevOps pipeline on a Linux agent and it deploys fine, albeit I've had issues with the alert being triggered but I suspect that error lies elsewhere. It is worth noting that this is a snippet, not the whole resource def, which is part of the larger template. Without that it of course will not deploy as you have not specified a resource to attach the alert to. The linked question seems to be more to do with their resource tags than anything else, and mine are correct. It still doesn't explain what the `$type` properties are actually **for**.